# Как производить математические операции в 16 СС

Tags: c#

Не думал что это могло стать такой большой проблемой.. Но я не могу найти информацию, как производить манупуляции в C# с шестнадцатиричными числами...

Как с ними работать, их постоянно в 10СС переводит.. хотя его никто не просит..

```
var num = {"6b", "af"};
string res = Math.Abs(Convert.ToByte(num[0], 16) + Convert.ToByte(num[1], 16)).ToString();
```

Результатом выполнения является int 282, вместо желаемых byte 11А

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Манипуляции с числами в любом случае производятся в двоичном виде, процессоры у нас двоичные. Отличаться может только форматы ввода/вывода. Поэтому не мудрите, излишне. Заведите переменные обычных числовых типов. Все операции выполняйте с их помощью, и уже полученный результат выводите в том виде, в котором нужно или удобно.

С вводом вы уже разобрались, судя по коду. Нехватает только правильного вывода.

"Из коробки" в .NET можно получить вывод в системах с основаниями 2, 8, 10, 16.
Для получения строкового представления по основанию 10, ничего делать не надо, достаточно вызвать метод `ToString()` для любого числа, включая дробные, это формат по-умолчанию.

Для получения строкового представления по основаниям 2,8,16 нужно использовать перегрузку [**Convert.ToString()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14kwkz77(v=vs.110).aspx), второй параметр которой определеят одно из 4-х доступных оснований. Существуют перегрузки данного метода для типов `byte`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, для остальных придется писать собственную реализацию `IFormatProvider` для класса `Convert` или какой-то свой конвертер.